# how to return a filed from a public struct class in ASP.NET MVC and show on view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, struct

i have some classes in my model folder that some of them can be table and some don't 
so i return my list for view and one filed get fill with a struct class 
my model is below

```
public class OffCode
    {
        [Key]
        public string OffCodeID { get; set; }
        public string GroupCode { get; set; }
        public int OffPercent { get; set; }
        public string UserPhone { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public Guid OffType { get; set; }
        public Guid Status { get; set; }
    }
public struct OffCodeStatus
{
    public static clsTextValue Unused = new clsTextValue("value1", new Guid("05F10464-6E4A-4B04-B5F7-141EEF8BA4B1"));
    public static clsTextValue Reserved = new clsTextValue("value2", new Guid("E31A89A7-1589-44C6-8A62-2214F1185B32"));
    public static clsTextValue Used = new clsTextValue("value3", new Guid("CD34E7D1-7C3C-4DD4-A3E2-B3CAA396FBE0"));
    public static clsTextValue Canceled = new clsTextValue("value4", new Guid("858AA2A7-4D31-4F0A-892E-31942CAD105F"));

    public static List<clsTextValue> GetFields()
    {
        return BaseDefines.GetFields(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    }
    public static clsTextValue FindByValue(Guid Value)
    {
        return BaseDefines.FindByValue(Value, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    }
}
```

this is my action

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {

        List<OffCodeStatus> off = new List<OffCodeStatus>();
        return View(db.OffCode.ToList());


    }
```

and now in my view i need to now how can i show my values that related with a record,for example instead of guid that shows in picture , i have to how value2 in public struct .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AijUS.jpg)

thank you all.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where is the code where you show this in your view?

Comment: Any reason you're using structs for this at all? Mutable structs are generally a bad idea, and unless you're careful you can get bitten by using them badly with reflection. (I'd also strongly advise you to rename `clsTextValue` to follow normal .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: The `struct` I see above contains only static members. No non-static field. So why is it not a `static class` instead of a `struct`? And what is it with the `List<>` of it? Every value of that type `OffCodeStatus` is the same "empty" value when it has no fields.